# Typescript - How do I add an extension method

Tags: typescript, extension-methods

I read that you can create extension methods in Typescript and I looked up some code

[image]

And put that code in my extension methods.ts but I get an error saying that toNumber doesn't exist. How can I fix this?

Comment: String has defined strictly interface. if you want to have another methods you need to define own string like `type MyString = String & {toNumber: ()  => number}`.

Comment: @MaciejSikora see example below 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend `String` interface by [augmenting global scope](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html):

```
export { };

declare global {
    interface String {
        toNumber(): number;
    }
}

String.prototype.toNumber = function (this: string) { return parseFloat(this) };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwNwFgBQWAmwDGANgIZTBwDmhEARsYYlnM3AJYB2MwUAZsfuQDKMKBwqNMLKXBgQAcgFcAtjW4AKAJQAuOO2WqoGSS2RZT2TMNHsKAOjBQIsmAE8wwW7MUrucALxwPArs+DCsEOxwajAAFqwAzjrxImIaiHBkMApQkWCk8cAAYtTEMNFx8WloWFj4EclwyVD+cADkAIytRnXsDXpKLU2e8vrqGka19RCEHtQUak3jQA)

Comment: What does export { }; do?

Comment: @MikeOttink You can augment global scope only in module. File considered module if it has imports or exports. So it is workaround to make it "module". If file has other imports or exports it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the `String` interface, like this:

```js
interface String {
    toNumber(): number;
}

String.prototype.toNumber = function(this: string) {
    return parseFloat(this);
}

const s = '123.45';
s.toNumber();
```