# Typescript - How to extend a class in a namespace?

Tags: typescript, extension-methods

I am working with Pixi.js and I was testing if I could extend the PIXI.Point. This lead me to post this question

[Typescript - How do I add an extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59089145/typescript-how-do-i-add-an-extension-method?noredirect=1#comment104413917_59089145)

But this is a followup question. Why is it throwing the following error?

[image]

Or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want using [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

Something like

```js
declare module '<PATH TO PIXI module>' {
  interface PIXI {
    Point: {
      zero(): PIXI.Point
    }
  }
}


PIXI.Point.prototype.zero = ...
```

Comment: I don't know whether it is because of having "export namespace"... but I cannot manage to make it work... Could you please show how to make it work if my original interface is placed inside namespace?