# Typescript Ambient type declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-declaration

I am trying to wrap a pure js library no exports, simply only a global variable with prototype extensions. https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs

**Declaration file is separate from npm library**

- Updated the typings file, after research found out that the correct way to go is to declare a class
- Still cannot import QRCode

```
declare class QRCode {

        constructor (el: HTMLElement, vOption: string|Options): IQRCode;

        public makeCode(sText: string): void

        public clear(): void
}

declare module 'davidshimjs-qrcodejs' {
    export enum CorrectLevel {
            M = 0,
            L = 1,
            H = 2,
            Q = 3
    }

    export interface Options {
            text: string,
            width: number = 256,
            height: number = 256,
            colorDark: string = '#000000',
            colorLight: string = '#ffffff',
            correctLevel: CorrectLevel
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the full error ?

Comment: QRCode is undefined, the global variable in the library

Comment: the typings arent correct that is the issue

Comment: So you're looking to how to augment global scope? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089554/1113002
Regarding importing - if it is global, just go with `window.QRCode`, import is not needed

Comment: Check the link to the library, you can see that the usage is a bit different. Everything is attached to QRCode global variable not window. I do not want to use it as part of window and want to add typescript support

Comment: yeah, everything  global in browser is attached to `window` (if you didn't know). you can use it without `window.` of course, just augment the global scope as in example above

Comment: I dont want to use it from window, I want to import it and use it as a typescript module. I check the window, totally forgot about it.

Comment: I checked several type declaration libraries and still no clue what is wrong. It seems I dont get the whole idea how the js library binds to the definition file

Comment: Again, you're trying to declare and import as module something that is not a module (think jQuery)